# Request to PWA start_url does not include cookies

Tags: flask, progressive-web-apps, firefox-android, google-chrome-android

Chrome and Firefox for Android don't seem to include cookies in the request to the [manifest `start_url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/start_url) when opening a Progressive Web App. My authentication system redirects the user to the login page. But as soon as the login page is refreshed, the user is redirected away from the login page because really they are already logged in.

Setting `start_url` to a different page that issues a 302 redirect back to the original page does not work either. However, a redirect using meta-refresh does successfully pass cookies to the page.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I now have a suspicion it's caused by my SameSite=Strict cookie policy, though I haven't had the time to test it yet. I still use the meta-refresh workaround.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the request doesn't supposed to include credentials. Use the following code on your header:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials">
```

Comment: I thought setting `crossorigin=use-credentials` only affects the GET /manifest.json request, not the request to start_url?

Answer (score 0):

Set `SameSite` cookie policy to `lax`

With SameSite=Strict the cookie will not be sent if you are visiting a link from a different web page, which is what happens when you open the PWA for the first time, and that's where SameSite=Lax comes in by allowing the cookie to be sent with these top-level navigations

Comment: Please explain the effect of what you propose and why it solves the problem described at the top of the page.

Comment: With `SameSite=Strict` the cookie will not be sent if you are visiting a link from a different web page, which is what happens when you open the PWA for the first time, and that's where `SameSite=Lax` comes in by allowing the cookie to be sent with these top-level navigations.

Comment: Thanks. Please [edit] to do that explanation in the answer post itself.